# Is there a specification for the format used by man pages?

Tags: man

I would like to parse man pages into a more structure form, but I'm unable to find a proper specification for the data format under use by man pages. Should I be looking for troff or nroff or groff or something else? groff(7) says

> The groff system has all features of the classical roff, but adds many extensions.

Are these extensions the various preprocessors like tbl or something else?

So far I've found the following resources:

- [troff.org](https://troff.org/) - This has historical notes and some tutorials, and some dead links.
- roff(7) ([OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/roff.7), [Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/7/roff)) - Doesn't really have a specification, only a brief overview and bunch of history.
- man-pages(7) ([Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/7/man-pages)) - This provides guidelines about sections in man pages (which is useful), but it doesn't talk about the data format.
- [A Typesetter-independent TROFF](https://www.krsaborio.net/unix/research/acrobat/8203.pdf) and [Troff User's Manual](https://proness.kix.in/plan9/mirror/sources/sys/doc/troff.pdf) - these are fairly old, so I can't really judge what the differences are between the troff in those papers and in practice.

Is there a clear specification somewhere for the exact format under use by man pages?

Comment: no standard - just similar/derived implementations.  You omitted one manpage, with the macros ([here](https://linux.die.net/man/7/man)).

Comment: @ThomasDickey, yes I looked at that but I don't know if that is comprehensive (my hunch is that it isn't).

Comment: sure it is not: but the point of your question is ***standards***, and there are **none**.

Comment: To clarify, does your comment mean "none of roff/troff/nroff/groff have standards" or "man pages in practice do not follow any particular *roff system" or both?

Comment: All of the `*roff` variants use the same instructions. Man pages add to those instructions a set of macros to do common things. But individual manpages may use either the underlying instructions or the macros or both with no consistency. ivanivan's answer, for example, is all about macros. But some pages hardly use the macros.

Comment: Parsing roff source for any purpose other than producing the output in a format that the author intended - you are probably doomed to fail. It's a low-level typesetting language, not a semantically structured document language. You might as well start with a printed man page and OCR it...

Comment: @ThomasDickey could you make your comment into an answer (possibly with some more resources that may be useful)?

Comment: It is unclear whether this is a question between roff/troff/nroff/groff or if it's asking about the actual macro package used by the manuals. Depending on Unix, the manuals may be written in any of a number of troff/nroff macro packages. If the question is about how to parse these markup documents, then it's basically a question about how to implement troff.

Comment: I am also not shure what the question is. The structure of the man pages is docuented here: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man5/man.5.html It may be of interest to check what Eric Raymond did approx. 15 years ago. He wrote a man page parser (IRC for an xml converter) On the other side there is a strange new program called `mandoc` that has a source code that is more then 3x larger than the sum of the whole UNIX text processing tools and still does not support everything you get from nroff/troff. So it does not make sense to attempt to write a troff replacement.

Comment: @Kusalananda the question boils down to: given an arbitrary (or typical) man page on my system (a) what is all the information I need to parse it (e.g. I need to know which flavor of roff is in use) and (b) where do I find that information (e.g. links to official sources for parsing roff flavors)? It seems that there are no specifications, so the best answer to (b) would have links to thorough sources.

Answer (score 1):

## There is no single source form.

Some people write manual pages in roff.  Almost no-one uses raw roff; but people write manual pages using various sets of roff macros, such as `an` or `mdoc`.  These macro sets differ extensively from one another.  But many people nowadays *do not write manual pages in roff at all*.

People can also author manual pages in Docbook XML, perl's POD, T<sub>E</sub>Χ, T<sub>e</sub>χinfo, ASCIIDOC, plain HTML, or other systems.

Some of these, most notably Docbook XML, are quite structured in the first place and the conversion to roff is lossy.  You are better off ignoring roff if they are the source, and using the actual source forms directly, which will likely already have the structured form that you are looking for.

Indeed, there *is no* roff intermediary when viewing some of these forms.  (All of the aforementioned can be converted directly to formats such as HTML without going through an intermediate roff stage.  Manual pages authored in Docbook XML, again notably, can even be viewed directly as the XML using several WWW browsers, without an HTML intermediary, if [Docbook CSS](http://www.badgers-in-foil.co.uk/projects/docbook-css/) or similar is employed.)

Many of these source forms are *themselves* standardized, but there is no single universal source form for manual pages.

## Examples

- [The Docbook XML source of the manual page for systemd's `systemctl` command (example: `systemctl halt`)](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/man/systemctl.xml)
- [The T<sub>e</sub>χinfo source of the manual page for GNU `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/doc/gdb.texinfo;h=2f9c68ac9326adac399cf5606e71e5941951d86c;hb=43662968f15ddbd815d64b4392a0171d8736f73a#l41609)
- [The POD source of the manual page for POD-Readme](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigpresh/Pod-Readme/master/README.pod)
- [The ASCIIDOC source of the manual page for the `asciidoc` command](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asciidoc/asciidoc/master/doc/asciidoc.1.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  Think like HTML... but pre-HTML.  Basically a bunch of typesetting macros for `groff` ...

First, there are some commonly agreed on sections - of course you can add more...

```
NAME
SYNOPSIS
DESCRIPTION
OPTIONS
BUGS
AUTHOR
SEE ALSO
```

And for each (and everywhere else) you use the `groff` typesetting macro syntax.

For example, a `TITLE HEADER` can be done like so -

```
.TH [name of program] [section number] [center footer] [left footer] [center header]
```

Or a `SECTION HEADER` -

```
.SH [section name]
```

And of course, you can bold, italic, underline, etc -

```
.B = bold
.BI = bold alternating italic
.BR = bold alternating Roman
.I = italic
.IB = italic alternating bold
.IR = italic alternating Roman
.RB = Roman alternating bold
.RI = Roman alternating italic
```

And you can even make comments in your text file -

```
." This is a comment
```

And then things like paragraphing (like the `<p></p>` html tag set) with `.PP`

Don't forget to name the file appropriately, and then `gzip` it when done.

This info (and more) is from http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/creatingman.htm

Comment: " Think like HTML... but pre-HTML" -- that is a bit hard, given that I am younger than HTML :P.

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate this answer is. man(1) page uses `.\"` for comments.

Comment: @theindigamer I only wrote one man page (out of curiosity, much like the OP seems to be) and it was a long time ago and I don't have the bookmark (maybe at work?).  My last sentence states where I got that info.

Comment: Note that manuals may not be written with the same macro package. If they are written [using `mdoc`](https://mandoc.bsd.lv/mdoc/), then the macros will be completely different.